# How to make this faster in generating combinations?

Tags: python, performance

I made a code to generate combinations based on first, second, third, fourth, fifth and sixth input. However, it is taking a long time: it usually takes 86-88 seconds.

Is there a faster and better way to do this?

```py
from itertools import combinations

x = [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]

combi = []

y = []
for c in combinations(x,6):
    combi.append(c)

first =  [1,2,4]
second = [6,9]
third =  [10,13,14,18,22,23,24]
fourth = [19,22,23,27]
fifth =  [25,29,34,35,38,39]
sixth =  [33,38,39,40,41,42]

print("generating...")
for i in combi:
    for a in first:
        for b in second:
            for c in third:
                for d in fourth:
                    for e in fifth:
                        for f in sixth:
                            if i[0] == a and i[1] == b and i[2] == c and i[3] == d and i[4] == e and i[5] == f:
                                y.append(i)
                                break
print(y, '\n')
print(len(y))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, generating a large number of combinations will always be slow. The first combination call will generate 13K results, which is a lot.

However, your second loop can be made more efficient. It seems like you are checking every combination to see if it is the combination you want. This is inefficient since you are spending a lot of computing power on many combinations that you can eliminate immediately.

Try something like this for the second loop:

```
for a,b,c,d,e,f in combi:
    if a in first and b in second and c in third and d in fourth and e in fifth and f in sixth:
        y.append((a,b,c,d,e,f))
```

Alternatively, you can use `itertools.product()` to replace the entire function (though the order might be slightly different if the order of x is different from the order of the other 6 lists):

```
y = itertools.product(first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth)
```

Comment: The OP's code is not equivalent to a Cartesian product. Consider cases where the numbers in the 6 lists are not in a perfectly identical order as the list `x`.

Comment: True, though in the given example the order is the same

Comment: If it isn't part of the OP's description of the question, then it can't be a valid assumption based on one set of sample input variables.

Comment: I agree. I have updated the post with a disclaimer

Comment: Note that checking `first`, `second`, etc. could be a bit faster if they are Python sets. Moreover, the multiple items can be checked at the same time by precomputing (partial) Cartesian products (`first`, `second`, etc.) of before the loop (put in a set for faster lookups). However, your solution should be fast enough anyway.

Comment: The first code you mentioned was so fast. 0.2 second. But question, in the second code, why does it output <itertools.product object at 0x000.... btw thank you for your answer.

Comment: @91divoc It will oputput an iterator instead of a list. You can use `list(y)` to get a list, of you can simply iterate over it with `for item in y`

Comment: Oh thank you very much. I’m learning a lot today.